# Persistent handling of request.credentials across page loads

Tags: jss, graphql, sxa-jss

I am using Sitecore 10.3 with SXA and Headless packages installed. I also have GraphQL installed. I am trying mutation after enabling the `/items/master` endpoint. But every time I have to change the playground settings of `request.credentials` from `omit` to `same-origin`.

The setting changes to `omit` everytime I refresh the page. Is there any way such that I can change the default settings to `same-origin`?